# How to you call the (paid) available holidays in a year?

Tags: word-usage

What are they called? Also, I'm interested in their adjectival version. Example:

> Anna hated the seven-to-five **nineteen-day-holiday** existence.

I wrote it like that, but I'm not sure if it's correct.

Comment: It is not clear whether you're asking about *vacation days* (days off that an employee earns at a particular rate, e.g., two weeks a year) or *holidays* (days like Christmas or, in the US, July 4, for which employees are paid even though they don't have to come to work), or both. Can you clarify?

Comment: I think what you wrote seems fine, although I would put a comma between _seven-to-five_ and _nineteen-day-holiday_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The terms generally used in the UK are **paid holiday** (informal) and **statutory leave entitlement** (formal). This is made up of a certain number of fixed days, called **bank holidays** or **public holidays** and the remainder where each employee can negotiate with the employer when he or she can take the holiday.